# The best way to pass Java reference down the chain of objects

Tags: java, parameter-passing

Let's consider a chain of objects like this:

```
Earth->Continent->Country->City->name
```

Let's also consider `Earth.class` has `public static void main(String[] args)`

When the application is executed with command-line option e.g. `Barcelona`, what would be the best way to pass it down to `City` object without introducing intermediate parameters?

Objects are created at different stages during program execution.

Should we make `name` variable static or use IoC such as Spring or Google Guice?
Are there other options?

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I like IOC best for this task. Let the IOC pass the dependency when it constructs the City.
- Alternative: Use a static service registry, which can be queried for a value. The City could get its name from the service registry.
- Alternative: Implement the Composite Pattern on your hierarchy, including a function such as find, which could return the City. Then you just have to query and set `earth.find(BarcelonaID).setName(args[0]);`

An example of how a IoC solution in PicoContainer would look like:

```
PicoContainer container = new DefaultPicoContainer();
container.addComponent(Earth.class);
container.addComponent(Continent.class);
container.addComponent(Country.class);
container.addComponent(City.class, new ConstantParameter(cityName));

City barcelona = container.getComponent(City.class);
```

Comment: Thanks, Christopher. IoC looks good, but initially needs infrastructure to fly, speaking of Spring and Guice. I wonder if such setup would be reasonable just to deliver several command-line arguments to the right place :)

Comment: @IvanBalashov The infrastructure is minimal. See the example.

Answer (score 2):

You can build data structures from the top-down -- the Continent constructs the city, or from the bottom-up -- `main` constructs the city and passes that to the Country, or using some combination.  DI favors the latter.

```
public static void main(String... argv) {
  // Bottom up.
  City city = new City(/* args relevant to city */);
  Country country = new Country(city, /* args relevant to country */);
  Continent continent = new Continent(country, /* args relevant to continent */);
  Planet planet = new Planet(continent, /* args relevant to planet */);
}

class City {
  City(/* few parameters */) { /* little work */ }
}
class Country {
  Country(/* few parameters */) { /* little work */ }
}
...
class Planet {
  Planet(/* few parameters */) { /* little work */ }
}
```

which can be much cleaner than top-down:

```
public static void main(String... argv) {
  // Top down.
  Planet earth = new Planet(
    /* all the parameters needed by Earth and its dependencies. */);
}
class Planet {
  Planet(/* many parameters */) { /* lots of work */ }
}
...
```

The DI folk maintain that the bottom-up construction leads to much more maintainable and testable code but you don't need a DI framework to use it.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. Fortunately, objects need to be built outside of Earth class. Otherwise, this would not be interesting :)

Comment: @IvanBalashov, I am advocating building them outside.

Comment: @MikeSamuel I don't think creating objects outside where they are supposed to be is a good idea. A country needs to know which cities belong to it, if you put this knowledge outside the `Country` class then you are violating object encapsulation

Comment: @GETah, When you construct the country, you tell it what cities are in it.

Comment: @MikeSamuel I see, by doing that, you are still exposing details that only the `Country` should know arn't you?

Comment: @GETah, exposing details that only the Country should know to what?

Comment: With encapsulation, it's more focused on how the object does what it needs to do.  The other principle to keep in mind is Single Responsibility - the country object should responsible for holding and perhaps manipulating the information in it, but most likely not loading it.  Loading something can happen in many different forms, even in the same application.  Depending on the setup, having objects load in and construct the object hierarchy so it can be used outside of the objects themselves can be quite a bit cleaner.  Also, note that testing is much easier when loading data separately.

Answer (score 1):

In my mind, this is the best use case you could imagine for a [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) pattern.
Basically, there should be one class `Parameters` that should hold all the parameters. Every object that needs one set of parameters can be visited with that `Parameters` class. The object can then pass the parameters to its children that know which parameters to use and how.
In your case, this can be done this way:

```
public interface IParameterized{
   public void processParameters(Parameters param);
}

public class Earth implements IParameterized{
   public Earth(){
      // Create all countries here and store them in a list or hashmap 
   }
   public void processParameters(Parameters param){
      // find the country you want and pass the parameters to it
      country.processParameters(param);
   }
} 

public class Country implements IParameterized{
   public Country(){
      // Create all cities that belong to this country
   }
   public void processParameters(Parameters param){
      // find the city you want and pass the parameters to it
      city.processParameters(param);
   }
} 

public class City implements IParameterized{
   public City(){
      // Create city...
   }
   public void processParameters(Parameters param){
      // Do something with the parameter
   }
}
```

**EDIT**
To wire up the dots, this can be used in the following way:

```
public static void main(String... argv) {
     Parameters params = new Parameters();
     // Populate params from the command line parameters
     Earth earth = new Earth();

     // Earth takes the responsibilty of processing the parameters
     // It will delegate the processing to the underlying objects in a chain
     earth.processParameters(params);
}
```

As a side note, you could also have a look at the [Chain Of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) design pattern

Comment: Thanks, GETah. But we still need to hold IParameterized object somewhere, and pass it to other objects, which means all references should be available at one place. I wonder if we could find something really decoupled :)

Comment: @IvanBalashov The parameters will be created in main and passed down the chain, please see my edit

Comment: Yes, but you have to have `Earth`, `City`, and rest of objects available inside `main()`, which are created elsewhere in my case...

Comment: @IvanBalashov Only `Earth` object will be created inside `main()` the other ones will be created in different places: `Countries` can be created anywhere else but should be references from `Earth` and so on.

Comment: @IvanBalashov Please see my edit. I have added constructors to the code to give you an idea of where different objects should be created